# access QR from a month ago

Tags: transactions

First of all, I am clueless about using bitcoin.
I sent money to a friend in Japan. I used a QR that I had used before. I did not see that he        wanted me to use a new QR. Apprently he cannot access that previous QR that I used by mistake.
He says  "There is a login info and password I need to access the main account online" and he does not have that. I have the long number underneath the "bar code".
I do not believe that he cannot access that QR from just a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

The QR code your friend sent you encodes a bitcoin address, which your wallet will use when creating a transaction that will pay your friend. So if you re-used the old QR code, that just means you sent BTC to the same address your friend wanted you to use in the past.

If your friend no longer has access to the private key for that old address (ie, he is locked out of the wallet for whatever reason), then they will be unable to spend the BTC you sent. The only way to recover those BTC, is to get access to that wallet/private key again.

> I do not believe that he cannot access that QR from just a few weeks ago.

You'll have to decide whether you trust this friend or not. It's difficult for me to say what the nature of the issue is on his end, but given the level of responsibility a bitcoin user must have in order to  secure their funds, it is not exactly routine to just 'lose access' to a wallet. Normally, it is recommended that every effort be taken to ensure you can securely maintain access to your wallet. If you don't, and access is lost, then your coins too will be lost forever.